# CakePhp 2 tree behaviour's generateTreeList() returns flat list

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-2.0

I followed the docs at the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) to use the tree behaviour.

Everything looks ok. parent_id, lft and rght are saved properly but
when I call:

```
$this->Model->generateTreeList()
```

The returned list is flat, i.e.:

```
array(
    (int) 8  => 'p1',
    (int) 11 => 'child of p1',
    (int) 9  => 'p2',
    (int) 2  => 'child of p2',
)
```

Is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected (according to documentation). generateTreeList returns array where key is id and diplay field is the value. 
`generateTreeList($conditions=null, $keyPath=null, $valuePath=null, $spacer= '_', $recursive=null)`
You can specify `$spacer` parameter, and have result like i.ex:

```
array(
  1 => 'p1',
  2 => '_p2',
  3 => '_p3',
  4 => '_p4',
  5 => '__p5',
);
```

The list is "flat" but with spacer. If you want to have hierarchical nested array you have to use: `$this->Model->find('threaded')`

Comment: You don't need to write a recursive function, just use `find('threaded')`.

Comment: No I have used the method call you already provided but the underscores are still not added. 'threaded' is in this case not what I need, I need the node's depth, does threaded provide that? I think it gave me a list with only depth of 1 (?)